# Do I need FCC certification to sell if my device uses ISM bands?

Tags: rf, fcc, certification

I have made a portable xbee-like transceiver. The system will be operating at 2.44000GHz (RX) and 2.46000GHz (TX). The TX power to the antenna is well underneath +30dBm; the EIRP is also less than +36dBm. My understanding is that even though my device is unlicensed and uncertified, and I am legally able to operate under these frequencies in the ISM band.

However, if I want to sell this device, do I need to have this device certified by the FCC? If so, what does it mean to be certified by the FCC for ISM bands?

P.S.
I only care about FCC certification, as I will be getting Intertek certification soon... and I don't really care about UL, cUL, or CE.

Comment: I agree with Olin below. You need some help from someone who's been through this and can get you finished. Don't expect any less than $10k-$20k in certification costs.

Comment: Yes, Gustavo is right. $10-20 k is a reasonable range. And, the less you know what you're doing, the higher the cost. If you've never been thru this process before, hire someone who has. Expect $150-200/hour, but that will still be cheaper than trying to get by doing this yourself when you've never been thru this process before. Don't get caught being penny-wise and dollar-foolish.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**All** intentional radiators must be certified to the FCC regulations.  Since you said "transceiver", it implies this device is in part a transmitter.  Selling a intentional radiator, such as your device, without FCC certification in the United States is a federal offense.  All your units can be confiscated, you can be fined, and in some cases worse punishments may be imposed.

Frankly, if you are asking such a basic question, you don't belong in this position.  Get someone who knows what they are doing to help you thru the process.  Then maybe next time you can be the expert.  This really not a place newbies belong without the guidance of someone that does know what they are doing.